# Google Maps + Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html

Could anyone advise how to get the directions to update when I alter the option in a select menu? The select is set to run onchange="function" I am just unsure where to put the function in this:

```
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 52.191933, lng: -2.225502},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }

        if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {                                                              //This gets the
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //users current
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //location
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //Creates variable for map coordinates
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
            var mapOptions = //Sets map options
                {
                zoom: 15,  //Sets zoom level (0-21)
                center: coords, //zoom in on users location
                mapTypeControl: true, //allows you to select map type eg. map or satellite
                navigationControlOptions:
                    {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //sets map controls size eg. zoom
                    },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //sets type of map Options:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
                };
            map = new google.maps.Map( /*creates Map variable*/ document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions /*Creates a new map using the passed optional parameters in the mapOptions parameter.*/);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
            var request = {
                origin: coords,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
                };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        });
        }
```